# Visual Studio C++/WinRT Core App vs Blank App

Tags: winrt-xaml, directx-11, c++-winrt, visual-studio-templates

If you are aiming to write a multi-threaded application with some intensive non-graphics background threads as well as a Direct3D based presentation layer which of the two Visual Studio templates Core App or Blank App is likely to be the better choice.

Given that I'd rather not write my own button/controls it seems like Blank App with XAML and using a SwapChain panel would be the go.

However, the statement "...app directly implementing CoreApplication" intrigues me, what if any are the benefits of directly implementing CoreApplication?

Comment: Tough decision. "Core" App here means UWP. You can use it sure, but it's kinda "deprecated" (google on it). The new kid in town for this is WinUI 3 (comes with the also new "Windows App SDK"): https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/1615 . Without UWP nor WinUI 3, you can't display XAML on Windows.

Comment: A "Core" application isn't tied to the UWP. You can implement a regular (unpackaged) Desktop application based on `CoreApplication`. Similarly, WinUI 2 can be used in a classic Desktop application. The real new kid in town is the [Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/), formerly known as Project Reunion. It comes with a [VSIX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProjectReunion.WindowsAppSDK-1-CPP-16), too. It is supposed to supersede the C++/WinRT and WinUI VSIX packages.

Comment: I am having a go at the Windows App SDK.